# How to prevent background-gradient from extending past the div when using scale

Tags: html, css

Currently, I have a radial-gradient as my background with a blur effect. Without a scale effect, it has white edges around the entire gradient. To combat this, I scaled the entire gradient, which works great, except for the fact it extends the page to the right, and allows the user to scroll left and right.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
.gradient{
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(62.61% 62.61% at 95.23% 6.02%, #160E71 0%, rgba(19, 13, 92, 0.26) 54.71%, rgba(90, 35, 248, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(72.48deg, #EF516D 2.61%, rgba(106, 103, 227, 0) 56.18%), radial-gradient(45.23% 45.23% at 35.11% -11.02%, #7936AE 0%, rgba(121, 54, 174, 0) 100%), radial-gradient(94.51% 124.88% at 94.32% 94.43%, rgba(65, 244, 255, 0.78) 0%, rgba(131, 218, 255, 0.6552) 32.29%, rgba(99, 175, 240, 0.3978) 64.06%, rgba(43, 90, 211, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(313.04deg, #341D65 0.93%, #604AEA 125.68%);
    background-blend-mode: normal, normal, normal, normal, normal, normal;
    filter: blur(100px);
    transform: scale(1.4);
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /* background-size: cover; */
    background-clip: padding-box;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.welcome-box {
    height: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-box">
        <div class="gradient"></div>
        
        <div class="welcome-box-content">
            <p class="welcome-subheader" style="font-style: italic">hi there,</p>
            <h1 class="welcome-header">I'm Mason Thomas!</h1>
            <p class="welcome-subheader">Connect with me!</p>
            <a href="https://github.com/Kandles11"><img src="assets/github.svg" alt="github logo" height="35" class="logo" /></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mason-thomas-ba1a891a1"><img src="assets/linkedin.svg" alt="linkedin logo" height="35" class="logo" /></a>
            <a href="mailto: mason@masongthomas.com"><img src="assets/email.svg" alt="linkedin logo" height="35" class="logo" /></a>
            <a href="/resume/resume.pdf"><img src="assets/resume.svg" alt="linkedin logo" height="35" class="logo" /></a>


        </div>
    </div>
```

neither the `background-size` or `overflow` attribute have an effect.

How can I make the gradient background fit the size of the page with the scaled effect? If this is not possible, how can I remove the white edges of the gradient background without the scaling effect? Thank you!

Here is a video of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mg4z.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width of .gradient to 100% will use its parent element as the total width and make .gradient the full width of its parent. Try updating the width to 100vw (viewport width). This will allow the gradient to be the width of the visible screen.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, the solution ended up changing the position of the parent div.

By changing the parent div to `position: relative`, the `overflow: hidden` property starting working, so my problem was solved.